# Compare index value and add class to the container

Tags: jquery

Created the carousel slider. I am unable to figure a logic to compare "slidesjs-index" & "data-item". If both the value are same, add class "active" to the "carousel-thumb--content".

How can I solve the issue?

**Carousel Slider:**

```
<div class="slides-item slidesjs-slide" slidesjs-index="0">
 <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1120x632"  />
 </a>
</div>

<div class="slides-item slidesjs-slide" slidesjs-index="1">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1120x632"  />
</a>
</div>
```

**Carousel Div container pagination:**

```
<div class="carousel-thumb">
  <div class="carousel-thumb--content">
    <a href="#" class="custom-item" data-item="0">
        <div class="carousel-thumb--text">
            <div class="carousel-thumb--title">Lorem ipsum dolor 1</div>
            <div class="carousel-thumb--desc">Ut fringilla augue eget quam lacinia</div>
        </div>
    </a>
  </div>

 <div class="carousel-thumb--content">
    <a href="#" class="custom-item" data-item="1">
        <div class="carousel-thumb--text">
            <div class="carousel-thumb--title">Lorem ipsum dolor 1</div>
            <div class="carousel-thumb--desc">Ut fringilla augue eget quam lacinia</div>
        </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script used for click function works fine. Using slide JS plugin for this carousel.

```
$('.custom-item').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.carousel-thumb--content').removeClass('active');
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');
   $('a[data-slidesjs-item=\'' + $(this).attr('data-item') + '\']').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first and foremost thumb rule is **please, don't invent new attributes**, instead use `data-*` attributes for **HTML 5**. So change your code to:

```
<div class="slides-item slidesjs-slide" data-index="0">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1120x632" />
  </a>
</div>

<div class="slides-item slidesjs-slide" data-index="1">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1120x632" />
  </a>
</div>
```

And then use the `.data()` method and `.closest()` to calculate and update what you want:

```
$('.custom-item').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.carousel-thumb--content').removeClass('active');
   $(this).parent().addClass('active');
   $(this).closest('a[data-index=\'' + $(this).attr('data-item') + '\']').trigger('click');
});
```

***Note:*** You may need to tweak my code a lil bit to make it work for you!

Comment: "slidejs-index" is the default attribute loads dynamically. I cant change this. Because we are using plugin on other components. Click function no issue in working. Only auto slide need to fix. On auto slide or prev or next button clicked, "active" class need to be added to "carousel--thumb-content"